# Get ObservableCollection from ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, observablecollection

Is there a way to determine the associated ObservableCollection programmatically from a ListBox?

I bound the ItemsSource to a ListBox in my XAML and when a user selects an item from within it, I want the program to find not only which ListBox the item came from (which I've managed to do) but also get the ObservableCollection associated with it.

I thought that by using sourceContainer.ItemsSource.ToString() (where sourceContainer is the programmatically-found ListBox) I would be able to determine the DataBound ObservableCollection behind it. However, this isn't the case. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Edit: Here's some code pertaining to the creation of the ObservableCollections and how I'm determining which box is selected. (I know it probably isn't the best way, I'm still learning...)

First off, the XAML (each ListBox has this line for general binding):

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOneItems}"
```

Now the code for creating the ObservableCollections:

```
    private ObservableCollection<DataItem> listOneItems;

    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> ListOneItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (listOneItems == null)
            {
                listOneItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
            }
            return listOneItems;
        }
    }
```

Here's where the program determines the parent of the selected item:

```
//Finds the name of the container that holds the selected SLBI (similar to finding the initial touched object)
FrameworkElement determineSource = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
SurfaceListBox sourceContainer = null;

while (sourceContainer == null && determineSource != null)
{
    if ((sourceContainer = determineSource as SurfaceListBox) == null)
    {
        determineSource = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(determineSource) as FrameworkElement;
    }
}

//Name of the parent container
strParentContainer = sourceContainer.Name;

//Name of the ObservableCollection associated with parent container?
```

If anything else is needed, let me know.

Comment: suppose you don't quite understand what do you need. if you are subscribed to listbox selection changed, you can get the listbox from sender object. var listbox=(ListBox)sender; and than get listbox.ItemsSource to get associated collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've bound directly to a property that is an `ObservableCollection<T>`, you should be able to do this:

```
var col = (ObservableCollection<MyClass>)sourceContainer.ItemsSource;
```

If that's not the case, you'll need to post the relevant XAML and code.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but for some reason it's still not working. When this line is hit, it's simply reading "Count = 1". I was hoping to have it read the actual name of the collection.

If what I'm saying doesn't make sense, please feel free to correct me. Databinding is still quite foreign to me.

Comment: That sounds like you are getting a list (ObservableCollection) back with 1 item? What do you mean by name? You should only care about the contents of a collection, not the name of the collection...that seems like a UI concern and some coupling to your business implementation that probably should not be there

Answer (score 1):

[Eren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507017/get-observablecollection-from-listbox/11507135#11507135) is correct, you can get the actual collection by casting the `ItemsSource` property to the correct collection type.

```
ObservableCollection<DataItem> sourceCollection = 
    sourceContainer.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<DataItem>;
```

If you only want the Name property as you suggested in the comment, you can get the `Binding` for the `ItemsSourceProperty` and look at the `Path` property

```
var binding = soureContainer.GetBindingExpression(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty);
var sourceCollectionName = binding.ParentBinding.Path.Path;
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up; I can see now why one wouldn't care particularly for the name of the ObservableCollection, as it has more useful functions outside of its name. I wish I could set both of these as best answers!

Comment: @NateFrueh I was wondering what on earth you wanted the `Name` property for :)

Answer (score 0):

The collection you associate with listbox is ObservableCollection? Cuz if you set an array - it doesn't make magic convertion to ObservableCollection in background.

Tell what for do you need this logic. Suppose smth is wrong in other logic.